# Check if a set of elements contains the event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'd like to check which of the elements in a set returned by jQuery is the `event.target` element.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I assume by "...which of the elements..." you mean the index of the element within the set. If you have the set in `set`, then [`index(element)`](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element) will give you the index (0, 1, etc.) or -1 if it isn't in the set at all:

```
var index = set.index(event.target);
```

---

Of course, if you just want to *do* something with the element, you don't need the set at all. Just use `$(event.target)` to get a new set containing that element.